# Change cell CONCAT value by small value in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don't really know how to explain this, but I have this column :

[image]

and this formula :
=CONCAT(H18;"|";H20;"|";H17;"|";H21;"|";H23) and this is what I expect :

[image]

How shall change my CONCAT by filter the small value in that column? (change that cell color would be nice too) just like the pic

Comment: Which cell is `H17`?  What do you mean by ***How change my CONCAT by filter the small value in that column?***  What version of Excel? More detail is needed.  Perhaps reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help you to edit your question to make it better.

Comment: EDIT : Cell column and number add. How change my CONCAT by filter the small value in that column? :  I have to manually see the small number ( with is C25 : 1,931768) , and then take 2 - 5 and add 3 (k=3) in the middle, so : 2|3|5. I want to know how dinamic chose the small number between (C12,C25,C51) . Obs: My english is bad. Obs 2 : Excel 2019

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do.  BTW, in Excel 2019 you have the `TEXTJOIN` function, so you could also use, for your given formula: `=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,H18,H20,H17,H21,H23)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, but this is what i understand, that you want to sort the data in column by smallest value and then CONCAT them

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,SORT(UNIQUE(H17:H23)))
```